# 404 not found error while working with mean stack application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, postman

I'm getting the error as 404 not found while trying to post data using postman in chrome.Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

I'm doing this application from the following link :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtIvu085uU0

here is my code.
app.js

```
//importing modules
var express=require('express');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var bodyparser=require('body-parser');
var cors=require('cors');
var path=require('path');

var app=express();
const route=require('./router/route');

//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlistapp');

//on connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected',()=>{
console.log('successfully connected to database mongodb @27017');

});

mongoose.connection.on('error',()=>{

    if(err)
    {

        console.log('Error in database connection:'+err);
    }


    });


//port number
const port=3000;



//adding middleware-cors
app.use(cors());

//bodyparser
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//adding routes
app.use('/api',route);

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//testing server
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.send('foobar');
});


app.listen(port,()=>{
console.log('serve started at'+port);

});
```

route.js

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const contact=require('../models/contacts');


//retrieving contacts
router.get('/contacts',(req,res,next)=>{
contact.find(function(err,contacts){
    res.json(contacts);
})

});



//retrieving data
router.get('/contacts',(req,res,next)=>{
res.send('Retrieving the contacts list');

});

//add contacts
router.post('./contact',(req,res,next)=>{
let newContact=new contacts({
first_name:req.body.first_name,
last_name:re.body.last_name,
phone:req.body.phone

})

newContact.save((err,contact)=>{
if(err){
res.json({msg: 'Failed to add contact'});

}
else{

    res.json({msg: 'contact added successfully'});

}
})

});

//delete contacts
router.delete('./contact/:id',(req,res,next)=>{
    contact.remove({_id:req.params.id},function(err,result){
if(err)
{
    res.json(err);
}
else{

    res.json(result);
}
    })
    });


module.exports=router;
```

contacts.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const ContactSchema=mongoose.Schema({
first_name:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
last_name:{

    type:String,
    required:true
},
phone:{

        type:String,
        required:true
    }

});

const contact=module.exports=mongoose.model('contact',ContactSchema);
```

Getting the following error in postman:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /api/contacts</pre>
    </body>
</html>

The following is the json data i'm trying to post:

    {
        "first_name":"anand",
        "last_name":"reddy",
        "phone":"1234567813"



    }
```

Comment: Why `router.post('./contact'` instead of `router.post('/contacts'`

Comment: You need to change your route from contact to contacts. You've made a typo

Comment: You are trying to access /api/contacts, but you have only specified /api/contact

Comment: hi,tried it that way still not working.

Comment: Share your postman url and whatever else you are including with it.  Most people are not going to watch the whole video, but if you have any headers, body, or auth.  That would help.

Answer (score 0):

`router.post('./contact'`  should be `router.post('/contacts`